# When is the integral of a function, a measure?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $S$ be the unit square. Given a function $f$ from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$, define a function $F$ from subsets of $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$, as:

$$F(A) = \iint_A f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$

What conditions on $f$ are sufficient to guarantee that $F$ is a finite measure on the Borel subsets of $S$?

I am thinking of the following conditions:

1. $f$ is non-negative;
2. $f$ is bounded;
3. $f$ is integrable.

If $f$ satisfies these conditions, is $F$ indeed a measure?

If not, what other conditions are required?

Comment: You also need to think which subsets you are defining F on.

Comment: For my purposes, it is probably sufficient if $F$ is defined on the Borel subsets of $S$, or on the Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $S$. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Well, yes, because if you are using the Lebesgue integral there are plenty of pathological subsets over which you cannot integrate. In fact that must be true for any integral, because you can easily find a subset A such that a countably infinite number of translates cover the unit square. If you give A zero measure, then the square has zero measure; if you give it non-zero measure, then the square has infinite measure.

Comment: OK, I changed the question to ask about Borel subsets of $S$.

Comment: I changed $\displaystyle\int\int_A$ to $\displaystyle\iint_A$ (the first is \int\int and the second is \iint with two "i"s) and also put small spaces before $dx$ and $dy$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, $F$ will be a measure. Moreover, whenever a measure $\mu$ defined on Borel sets satisies $\lambda(A)=0\implies\mu(A)=0$ with the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, there exists a basically unique function $f$  such that $\mu=F_f$.

Comment: In fact, you do not need condition 2).